# Implementation of pagination over Elastic Search data (more than 10000 records) created from denormalized data of sql?

Tags: mysql, performance, elasticsearch, kibana, system-design

I am currently working on a project which has large amount of data (around 10K-20K entries per day). We have stored data into our primary database **MySQL** and entire de-normalized data into **Elastic Search**. We are using Elastic Search database for representing dashboards & download reports.

Now problem arises when we have to *paginate data in dashboard*.

We can use size and from parameters to display by default up to 10000 records to your users. If we want to change this limit, we change index.max_result_window but that may lead to internal memory issues. Other possible solution might be Scroll API but that has some constraints over time frame. What is best possible way to perform pagination in large data set. Also the functionality must include pagination where user can move to all possible page number displayed onto client side dashboard.

Comment: Take a look at "Search After" https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after

Comment: How can I implement the functionality of pagination where user can move to all possible page number displayed onto client side dashboard.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? In same position.

Comment: No...still waiting for better answers